# Removing a character from a SET datatype column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database which stores location data for different physical locations. Depending on what these buildings are being used for, a single location can be used for up to nine different, predetermined "categories"; each of these categories corresponds to a number. I have a function that takes user input and adds the correct number to the column. This column is the SET datatype (It's important that I keep these numbers in ascending order.)

I would like to be able to remove one specific number from this SET without touching any of the other numbers within the SET. I have tried something along these lines:

```
"UPDATE locations SET type = REPLACE(type,$type,'') WHERE locationname = '$value'";
```

However, nothing seems to happen when I run this query, and there are no errors being reported.

Comment: It would be better to use a second table with two columns: one the id of your building and a second one with the category. You're asking for trouble, if you store list of values in one field. Violating the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) of databases is usually a bad database design.

Comment: So, what code have you written to execute this query and fetch error messages?

Comment: @VMai Okay I understand what you're saying...that actually makes way more sense and it will save me some headaches later, I should think. Thanks a lot for the tip! Oh and I'm new to the site, is there a way I can upvote your comment or something?

Comment: I rewrote my comment as answer. You can accept this answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to use a second table with two columns: one the id of your building and a second one with the category. You're asking for trouble, if you store list of values in one field. Violating the first normal form(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) of databases is usually a bad database design.

Answer (score 0):

w/o knowing the table layout, I would first suggest to qoute that properly:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `locations` SET `type` = REPLACE(`type`,'" . $type . "','') 
   WHERE `locationname` = '" . $value . "'";
```

next would be good to know whether there are any errors thrown in the log and what the values are.

Comment: I have decided to redesign this bit so that I won't use the SET datatype anymore, but rather a separate table which will hold all the types for each location. I do appreciate your swift reply, however!